# Form elements not visible over SVG background in React application

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, next.js

I'm working on a Next application where I have a form element inside an SVG background. The problem I'm facing is that the form elements are not visible over the SVG. Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
<section className="h-screen w-full relative">
  <svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    viewBox="0 0 1543 1355"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    fill="none"
  >
    <path
      d="M423.63 46.4301L8 140.302V1001.51L771.5 1346L1535 1001.51V140.302L1119.37 46.4301C890.932 -4.81004 652.068 -4.81004 423.63 46.4301Z"
      fill="#D3C189"
      stroke="#EB596E"
      strokeWidth="15"
    />
    <form
      onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}
      className="absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2"
    >
      <h2 className="text-2xl text-center">Add Missions</h2>
      <Input
        placeholder="Run 3 miles"
        className="placeholder:italic"
        value={text}
        onChange={handleText}
      />
      <Button type="submit">Add</Button>
      <ToastContainer />
    </form>
  </svg>
</section>
```

I've tried adjusting the z-index and positioning, but the form elements remain hidden behind the SVG. How can I make the form elements visible and interactable over the SVG background?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Attached: Current display [image: Current display]

Comment: In order to embed HTML into SVG you may need to enclose the form in a <[foreignObject>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject)

Comment: @enxaneta Thanks for the info! It worked but as not I expected. So, I am still searching for a solution